# ServiceStack Ormlite usage in ServiceInterface

Tags: c#, mysql, ormlite-servicestack

I have created a solution using the empty asp.net template.
I have addred Ormlite and MySql Servicestatck libraries and configured them in the Apphost.cs

```
        ConnectionStringSettings connstring = ConfigUtils.GetConnectionStringSetting("Nice2NoConnection");
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connstring.ToString(), MySqlDialectProvider.Instance));


        // Below we refer to the connection factory that we just registered
        // with the container and use it to create our table(s).
        using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
        {
            // We’re just creating a single table, but you could add
            // as many as you need.  Also note the “overwrite: false” parameter,
            // this will only create the table if it doesn’t already exist.
            db.CreateTable<Channel>(overwrite: false);
```

What I am having trouble figuring out is how to access the OrmliteWriteExtensions which include Save() in the ServiceInterface project.  I tried adding Ormlite and MySql there but don't know how to access the reference of the connectionfactory in this project.

I think my issue relates to a lack of deeper understanding of IoC
I am probably over complicating something here.

Suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the feedback. I wish to thank you for such a fantastic library. My issues turns out was my lack of understanding of IoC and I had to do code like:             `var conn = HostContext.Container.Resolve<IDbConnection>();
                conn.Open();
                conn.Save<Channel>(channel);`

Answer (score 0):

The OrmLite extension methods are under the `ServiceStack.OrmLite` namespace so to access them you just need to import:

```
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
```